# Summarize changes of several changesets in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have several checkins related to a single work item. Is there a way to get a summary of all these checkins, so I can see the difference between files before I've started working on them (like, at the moment of changeset A), and their final form (changeset B)? I would use `View history` and compare the folders of changeset A and changeset B, but that will give me lots of diffs that were made by other people in different files that are of no interest to me.

**Edit**: As suggested by *Patrick-MSFT*, I tried to use TFS Sidekicks, but for some reason I don't seem to get any result whatever combination of filters I use.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried created a query to get the work item first? And then select the created query in the TFS Sidekicks tool?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using **TFS Sidekicks**. You can search for your single work item and it will give you a consolidated view.

> 1. Install [**sidekicks**](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) for your relevant TFS version
> 2. Open side kicks and connect it to TFS (usual tfs dialogue)
> 3. Click **Tools** -> **Code Review Sidekick**
> 4. Click by Work Items and select the appropriate Project and Query (TFS explorer workitem query). Alternatively, you can search by
>      changesets
> 5. Select the appropriate work item.
> 6. This will show **all the changes for that work item**

In your case , you want to compare all of the changes to a file,
    from its state before the first checkin of this workitem and the
    last checkin of the workitem (collapse all of the changes)
    enter code here

Right click the file you are reviewing, the one associates with the
    highest changeset number, and select ***'compare with previous (not in
    view)'*** This will show you the **complete difference in your VS configured
    diff tool.**

*Note:* If the file is new and has multiple checkins, select the
    one with the maximum changeset it, and select ***'compare with oldest
    in the view'***

Comment: You are giving the example about a single file diffs, but in my case there are several files being added/changed/deleted - would it work on entire changeset, or I would have to manually select several files that I'm interested in? Not at work till Monday, so can't check this solution.

Comment: This is also work on entire changeset. And you can also manually select several files. It's based on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solution once I get back to TFS.

Comment: For some reason there are no results at all for any project+query, with any filters, just empty tables. Tried .vsix and standalone version, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: It works well on my side. Could you add your screenshot of using TFS Sidekicks in your update question. And did you have enough permission ? Since I'm team project administrator in that team project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tf difference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/difference-command) command to compare the changes between two changesets for a specified file.

```
tf difference /version:669~672 program.cs /format:Context
```